# StaticTransformBroadcaster does not broadcast

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I tried to implement a simple StaticTransformBroadcaster with the following code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf2/transform_datatypes.h>

#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Transform.h>

void publishStaticTransformation();
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "StaticBroadcaster");

    ROS_INFO("StaticBroadcaster started");
    publishStaticTransformation();
    ros::spin();
}

void publishStaticTransformation()
{
    tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster staticBroadcaster2;

    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped msg;
    msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

    msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    msg.child_frame_id = "child_2";

    msg.transform.rotation.x = 2.0;
    msg.transform.rotation.y = 2.0;
    msg.transform.rotation.z = 0.0;
    msg.transform.rotation.w = 1.0;

    msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
    msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
    msg.transform.translation.z = 0;

    staticBroadcaster2.sendTransform(msg);
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("published");
}
```

This doesn't work but i don't know why. "published" is printed on the Console but rqt_graph shows no connection between my broadcaster and the tf_static topic.
However, wehn I Create the StaticTransformBroadcaster first and pass it as an argument to my publishStaticTransformation-method it works.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf2/transform_datatypes.h>

#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Transform.h>

void publishStaticTransformation(tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster &staticBroadcaster);

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "StaticBroadcaster");

    ROS_INFO("StaticBroadcaster started");
    tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster staticBroadcaster;
    publishStaticTransformation(staticBroadcaster);
    ros::spin();
}

void publishStaticTransformation(tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster &staticBroadcaster)
{
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped msg;

    msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

    msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    msg.child_frame_id = "child_2";

    msg.transform.rotation.x = 2.0;
    msg.transform.rotation.y = 2.0;
    msg.transform.rotation.z = 0.0;
    msg.transform.rotation.w = 1.0;

    msg.transform.translation.x = 0;
    msg.transform.translation.y = 0;
    msg.transform.translation.z = 0;

    staticBroadcaster.sendTransform(msg);
}
```

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191262/statictransformbroadcaster-does-not-broadcast/) by [TheElk](https://answers.ros.org/users/20089/theelk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason was  [tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/static__transform__broadcaster_8h_source.html) has a [ros::publisher](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html) to publish transforms.

In the first case `tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster staticBroadcaster2` go out of scope , all the callback will be stopped being callded, which is not the case for second one.

---

From [ros::Publisher Class Reference](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html)

*Once all copies of a specific Publisher go out of scope, any subscriber status callbacks associated with that handle will stop being called. Once all Publishers for a given topic go out of scope the topic will be unadvertised.*

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheElk](https://answers.ros.org/users/20089/theelk/) on 2014-08-26**:
Tank you very much for your answer !